# Tile Icon Windows Desktop App using MSDN help is not working

Tags: winapi, sdk, desktop, tiles, windows-8.1

I am trying to create a tile icon for the windows 8.1 using the guide provided by Microsoft here. I have done everything they are asking me to do  there but I am still not seeing the Tile Icon. Has this worked for anyone? can someone please help? It is picking my brain and can't sleep!!! Please help!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj673981

```
<Application xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">; 
    <VisualElements BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="off" ForegroundText="light" Square150x150Logo="Assets\150x150Logo.png"/> 
</Application>
```

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: there is no code. if you actually read the documentation they just ask you to create a folder for image and generate the pri file using makepri.exe. a few steps to follow but I dont think it relates to any code compilation as far as I can tell.

Comment: All right, show your application manifest.

Comment: <Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <VisualElements
        BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
        ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="off"
        ForegroundText="light"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\150x150Logo.png"/>

</Application>

Comment: the above contents are in a file named AppName.visualelementsmanifest.xml

Comment: Removing the semicolon would help.

Comment: I just tried it. still not working. seems straight forward but somehow not able to get the image to show up in the start menu. still shows the App Icon. Were you able to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your visual manifest only specifies a 150x150 image.  You need to [specify both](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx):

> **Important**  If you opt for a custom image, you must specify an image
>   for both the Square150x150Logo and Square70x70Logo attributes. If you
>   specify only one of those attributes, this entire XML file is ignored
>   and the default styling (app icon and background) is applied to the
>   tile.

I created a sample and specified both images, and it works fine for me.

Also, don't forget to [refresh the shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx#important__refresh_your_shortcut_file):

> Step 7: Important! Refresh your shortcut file
>
> If your app is already installed, you must nudge your shortcut after
>   the new or updated .VisualElementsManifest.xml is in place or it will
>   be ignored.

Comment: Worked! appreciate your help! I never would have thought this could have been a problem! thank you!